# Child classes overwrite each other's methods

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

thanks to help from stackoverflow posters I have set up some oop javascript. However, I have hit another snag.

I have two different classes with the same inheritance. They then both have a function named the same, but doing different things. The trouble is, if ClassB is defined last, then even when I have a ClassA object, and write classAInstance.MyFunction(); it returns 2, ie ClassB's function of the same name.

```
BaseClass = function(){
    ...init some stuff...
};

ClassA = function(){
    BaseClass.call(this);
    ...init some stuff...
};
ClassA.prototype = BaseClass.prototype; // innherit
ClassA.prototype.MyFunction(){
    return 1;
};

ClassB = function(){
    BaseClass.call(this);
    ...init some stuff...
};
ClassB.prototype = BaseClass.prototype; // innherit
ClassB.prototype.MyFunction(){
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: +1 good questions deserve upvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why is because both ClassA and ClassB's prototype is pointing to the same object.  I'm not sure what your use case is for this but it would be just as well to have the prototype be an instance.

```
ClassA.prototype = new BaseClass();

...

ClassB.prototype = new BaseClass();
```

Comment: Wow, thanks everyone. That did the trick. I cannot believe you all answered so quickly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that objects are passed by reference not value!

(Well actually, technically it IS by value, but for arguments sake that value is a reference).

The point is, when your are setting ClassA.prototype.myFunction, you are defining a new function on BaseClass's prototype, because remember ClassA.prototype = BaseClass.prototype.

So, then when you set ClassB.prototype.myFunction, you are again overwriting BaseClass.prototype.myFunction, and then subsequently your ClassA's function!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to perform inheritance in JS. The issue you're running into is that **all three** classes are actually the same because they *all* reference the object at `BaseClass.prototype`.

One of the short ways of inheriting from a simple base class is to use:

```
ClassA.prototype = new BaseClass();
```

and

```
ClassB.prototype = new BaseClass();
```

This will fall apart for fancier classes, (i.e. classes that involve parameters) to the constructor. I remember that Douglas Crockford had a function that can be used to do a fancier version of extending, however I'm unable to find it at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting up the prototype of the new classes incorrectly

```
BaseClass = function(){
    ...init some stuff...
};

ClassA = function(){
    BaseClass.call(this);
    ...init some stuff...
};
ClassA.prototype = new BaseClass(); // innherit
ClassA.prototype.MyFunction(){
    return 1;
};

ClassB = function(){
    BaseClass.call(this);
    ...init some stuff...
};
ClassB.prototype = new BaseClass(); // innherit
ClassB.prototype.MyFunction(){
    return 2;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Normally you wouldn't want to have two functions with the same name in any network of objects which nest into or inherit from eachother. Why not rename the second `MyFunction(){` to something else?

Comment: What do you call `interfaces` in strongly typed OOP languages?!